# Delphi Vcl Metro application issue when minimizing then maximizing application

Tags: delphi, vcl, minimize

I've written a Vcl Metro application with several forms that I have to open sequentially.
I'm using Rad Studio 10.1 Berlin
I've added a button on every form to miminize application if user need it.
The issue happens when:

```
1) Open main form
2) Open second form
3) Open third form
4) Minimize application
5) Restore application.
```

At point 5 (when click on desktop bar to maximize application) the application will show Form2 instead of form3

The code

```
//On Main form (Form1)
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if not Assigned(form2) then
   form2:=tform2.Create(self);
   form2.show;
   form2.BringToFront;
end;

//On Second form (Form2)
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if not Assigned(form3) then
   form3:=tform3.Create(self);
   form3.show;
   form3.BringToFront;
end;

//On third Form
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
APPLICATION.Minimize;
end;
```

Comment: Try setting the `PopupParent` property of each Form to control z-ordering issues. Set `Form2.PopupParent=Form1`, and `Form3.PopupParent=Form2`

Comment: @RemyLebeau It works!! Thank you  very much.